# Connect Jdbc to Sql server using SSMS 19

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

I am trying to connect a script i wrote for a google sheet in App script which ideally should connect the Database (local) to the sheet. But i always run into error :
`Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. transferDataToSqlServer @ Code.gs:11`

i tried enabling  tcp/ip ports , numerous chatgpt stuff and what not but it doesnt work.

the code is :

```
function transferDataToSqlServer() {
  // Fetch data from Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Establish connection to SQL Server using SQL Server Authentication
  address = 'DESKTOP-E15Q53Q\SQLEXPRESS';
          user = 'testing';
          userPwd = 'testing';
          dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;databaseName=Testing';
          var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
}
```

Comment: i feel like the app script isnt being allowed by the window to contact sql server , because when i write a python script and run it , the connect is fairly established . I am really looking for something to help me .

Comment: Isn't google sheet running in some galaxy far away? How will it find DESKTOP-E15Q53Q which i'm guessing is local on your network at home?